# Changing quantity on amazon with vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I try to open the Amazon website, pick a product, go to the cart, press cart and change the quantity (for example 450). I have a problem to solve the last step to change the quantity.

[This is the quantity button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUgXq.jpg)

I tried this:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With objIE`

Set Element = .document.getElementsById("dropdown1_9")
Element.Click
```

and this:

```
Set Element = .document.getElementsByName("quantatiy").value = 10 
End with
```

Both don’t work. I think I don’t know the type of button, which i am trying to manipulate.

Could somebody help me with the problem? What can I do to change the quantity?

Comment: quantatiy is that the correct spelling? also add some waits to check IE is ready.

Comment: try something more like:

`Set Element = .document.getElementsByName("quantatiy").selectedindex = 1 `

You sure about the spelling too?

Comment: Coding against a front end, like a web store, can be dangerous.  What happens if Amazon update their site tomorrow and the latest version uses different names?  You code could fail or start to behave in unpredictable ways (perhaps by ordering unwanted items).  Wherever possible you should code against an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: I don't think it's a combo in that way, it looks like a normal text entry with an icon to show as a combo, but it's not a combo until clicked.   a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-mini I got elements by this class name, used index of (0) and then got the contents

Comment: sorry a-button-text a-declarative

Answer (score 0):

I used this, I've not put the code in to navigate to the basket, but it does what you're asking, not sure of its future proofing tho.

```
Public Sub test()


Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim e As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "www.amazon.co.uk"

While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set objDoc = objIE.document

Set ele = objDoc.getElementsByClassName("a-button-text a-declarative")

Set e = ele(0)

e.innerText = 2

End Sub
```